# Using std::vector iterators in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety, stdvector

I've run into an issue while multithreading my application, and it appears to come down to not *quite* understanding how `std::vector` interacts with a thread.

Generally speaking, I understand that I can have as many concurrent readers as I'd like, and if I have a writer, I should use a `std::mutex` to lock my thread so no other readers or writers can access my vector while I am writing to it.

However, I have an example where I am only reading using an iterator, and this seems to crash my code.

For example, the following code:

```
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        numbers.push_back(std::rand());
    }

    for (auto& it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "Number : " << (*it) << std::endl;
    }
```

works just fine for printing out a list of random numbers.  But if I simply put the second for loop in a thread:

```
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        numbers.push_back(std::rand());
    }

    std::thread([&]() {
        for (auto& it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
            std::cout << "Number : " << (*it) << std::endl;
        }
    });
```

Then this crashes with a Access violation writing location every time.  I tried to think of what could go wrong.  My first thought was, perhaps `numbers` is going out of scope, so what if I capture by copy?

```
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        numbers.push_back(std::rand());
    }

    std::thread([=]() {
        for (auto& it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
            std::cout << "Number : " << (*it) << std::endl;
        }
    });
```

Same error.  If I create a class and make `numbers` a member variable, same issue.  So it doesn't seem to be an issue with the variable falling out of scope.  I even tried performing some logic other than `std::cout` just in case writing to the console was causing issues, but that isn't it either.

I'm sure that I'm missing some nuance about using `std::vector` with multiple threads, but I can't quite figure it out -- can anyone point out my mistake?

thanks!

Comment: `std::thread(anything);` results in [the program being terminated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) via a `terminate` call., by way of `~thread` destructor being called on a `thread` object that hasn't been `join`ed or `detach`ed. Ain't got nothing to do with the vector, and everything to do with a temporary `thread` object being destroyed at the semicolon.

Comment: Wow, I feel like a doofus!  That's an embarassingly trivial mistake!